# How to remove last created QgsRubberBand by clicking in Map Canvas area where doesn't exist any feature?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

By combining information from these posts:

[Get the identified feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259016/get-the-identified-feature/260214#260214)

[How to create and remove multiple QgsRubberBands in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145010/how-to-create-and-remove-multiple-qgsrubberbands-in-pyqgis/146367#146367)

I produced following code for getting feature attributes and creating and removing its respectives **QgsRubberBand**s after clicking on Map Canvas where features exist for a polygon vector layer.

```
from qgis.gui import QgsRubberBand, QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
    fid = feature.id()
    rbList.append( [feature.id(), QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(), True)])

    print ("feature selected : " + str(fid))

    for i, item in enumerate(feature.attributes()):
        print (feature.fields().names()[i] + ": " + str(item))

    if len(rbList) == 2:
        iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(rbList[0][1])
        del rbList[0]

    rbList[0][1].setColor( QColor( 'red' ) )
    rbList[0][1].setWidth( 5 )
    rbList[0][1].addGeometry(feature.geometry(), None) 

rbList = [] # To store the created rbs and feature ids

layer = iface.activeLayer()
mc=iface.mapCanvas()
mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mc)
mapTool.setLayer(layer)
mc.setMapTool(mapTool)
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified)
```

After running above code, it can be observed that it works as expected (see following images):

[image]

[image]

however, I cannot find out any useful method (at pyqgis script) for removing last created **QgsRubberBand** by clicking in Map Canvas area where doesn't exist any feature. It could be manually done by using following instruction at Python Console:

```
iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(rbList[0][1])
```

My question is how can I implement former instruction in the previous code to get expected result.